# Finding class number of quadratic number field using Minkowski bound

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain, ideal-class-group

My understanding of this is as follows:

In the general case, one has a quadratic number field $F$, which is always of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some square-free integer $d$.

Minkowski Bound Theorem states that every equivalence class in the ideal class group $C_F$ of an algebraic number field $F$ of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $r_2$ complex embeddings, contains a non-zero ideal $I$ with norm $$N(I)\leq (\frac{4}{\pi})^{r_2}\frac{n!}{n^n}\sqrt{|d_F|}$$ where $d_F$ is the discriminant of $F$.

So once the Minkowski bound (RHS of inequality) is established, bearing in mind that $N(I)$ must be positive integer also, I have read that it is only necessary to factorise the principal ideals $(p)=pO_F$ into a product of prime/maximal ideals for $p\leq$ the Minkowski bound. Why is this? And is it the case that since $O_F$ is a Dedekind ring, that these ideal divisors of $(p)$ are prime iff maximal?

I am a bit confused about how to proceed from here in the case where the Minkowski bound is $\geq 2$ and primes have to be checked.

So one can determine whether $p$ splits in $F$, ramifies in $F$ or remains prime, for each prime $p$. How is this information used to compute the ideal class group $C_F$ and corresponding class number?

An illustrative example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hopefully this will still be useful to you, or to someone in the future with a similar problem.

You have a number field $F$ and you want to find its ideal class group $C_F$. By Minkowski Bound Theorem every ideal class is represented by an ideal $I$ of norm $N(I) \leq c$ where $c$ is the Minkowski constant. So in order to find the elements of the class group, we need to find ideals of small norm in $O_F$.

There is a very important fact about ideals in rings of integers: $N(I) \in I$, so $I \mid (N(I))$. Now $N(I)$ is a natural number and can be factorised in the product of rational primes. So if we can factorise into primes all ideals $(p)$ with $p \leq c$, we will be able to find all ideals of small norm as their factors.

(Indeed prime and maximal ideals in Dedekind domains coincide.)

---

This is perhaps best illustrated by an example. Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{26})$. Then $O_F= \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{26}]$, $n=2$, $r_2=0$ and $d_F=4\cdot 26 = 104$. The Minkowski bound is $c=\sqrt{26}<6$, so we need to find all prime ideals of norms $\leq 5$.

By Dedekind's Theorem for primes $2,3$ and $5$, we see that they factorise as

$(2) = (2, \sqrt{26})^2 =: P_2^2$ is a product of two prime ideals of norm $2$.

$(3)$ remains prime, so it has norm $9$, which is too large for our interest (*ie* the Minkowski Bound tells us that the same class is also represented by some ideal of smaller norm).

$(5)= (5, 1+\sqrt{26})(5, -1+\sqrt{26}) =: P_5 \cdot P_5'$ is a product of two distinct prime ideals of norm $5$.

Therefore, all ideals of norm $\leq 5$ in $O_F$ are $P_2, P_5$ and $P_5'$ and the ideal class group is generated by their classes $[P_2]$, $[P_5]$ and $[P_5']$. We have some relations between these already: $[P_5]$ and $[P_5']$ are inverses (because their product is a principal ideal) and $[P_2]$ has order $2$. Then we also observe that $(6-\sqrt{26})=P_2 \cdot P_5$ and so $[P_2] \cdot [P_5] = 1$ too and so $[P_2]=[P_5]=[P_5']$. After checking that the ideal $P_2$ is not principal, this means that the ideal class group has order $2$.

---

I hope this example was helpful and I'm happy to answer any further questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - I found it very useful. Is it possible to expand explicitly on using Dedekind's theorem to find the norm of the prime ideals?